# izpack without run-privileged cannot write to C:\MyDirName

Tags: windows-7, permissions, izpack

I have a custom Java app and an IzPack installer. For years, in my izpack build file I had the following:

```
<run-privileged condition="izpack.windowsinstall.vista|izpack.windowsinstall.7"/>
```

The problem is that some of the users do not have admin privilege on their PCs, but they still want to be able to install the package. If I remove the above, they can run the installer but then it complains "This directory cannot be written!", when they try to install in the default location, which is C:\OPENDCS.

Yet the same user can create this directory either from a CMD or an Explorer window.

Is there a way to allow the izpack installer to create a directory directly under C:\ without running as an administrator?

Answer (score 0):

You could package your directory create operations in a `create-dirs.bat` batch file, which you would mark `<executable>` and execute `stage="postinstall"`. This way the directory creation will be executed with the given user's permissions, which (according to your post) should work just fine.

*EDIT 29/02/2016*: You would put this file into a first "dummy" `<pack>`,  mark it `<executable>` and execute `stage="postinstall"` as stated above, which would execute it **after this first** *dummy* **pack was installed**. At the installation of the next pack (i.e. your first *useful* pack) you will already have the folder created.

Note that `postinstall` will not run the batch file *after the installation*, but *after the* `<pack>`'s *installation*.

Comment: Good suggestion, and if this were some ancillary directory needed by the app your solution would work. But the directory I need to create is the $INSTALL_PATH, so postinstall is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the behavior with izpack v5.0.7. The problem you mentioned should be fixed with this issue: https://izpack.atlassian.net/browse/IZPACK-1355